# Keyboard not working in GRUB

Tags: grub2, keyboard

I have an MSI all-in-one PC with windows 10 and ubuntu. Usually I would start it up and go to ubuntu booting page and I had configured it in a way so that if I don't select any options after 3 seconds it would start the first option which was Win 10. But after updating to ubuntu 23 my keyboard doesn't work anymore on the booting page and also the first option has changed to memory test (with a blue screen) so now there is no way for me to select any operating system. What should I do? onboard or external keyboard on neither of usb slots works. also fast boot is on and I can't go to bios setting.
[image]

Comment: What keyboard are you using? Is it the onboard keyboard or an external one? Can you connect an external one? Does the keyboard have separate number keys? Do you perhaps have the numLock enabled? What happens if you press `e` instead of the arrow keys? Please ***[EDIT]*** your question and add the answers.

Comment: Can you access the BIOS settings? If the keyboard works in BIOS but not in GRUB, see if there are BIOS settings for "USB legacy compatibility" or similar, and see if changing them has any effect. If your system has both PS/2 and USB connectors, and you are currently using a USB keyboard, borrow a PS/2 keyboard for testing, and vice versa. Also test your current keyboard with another computer, if possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally fixed it by holding the power button which took me to BIOS setting directly.

Comment: This appears to only be half an answer. You figured out how to get into the BIOS on your hardware, but your answer here says nothing about your issues with your keyboard, which seems to have been the main problem.

Comment: You don't have to downvote for a half answer. It somehow got fixed after I logged into windows and now the keyboard works.

Comment: Now you've made it even more unclear. Was the issue resolved in Windows (by magic) or by editing some settings in BIOS?

Comment: It probably had something to do with "fast boot" in bios.